# jquery focus on next input of more than one type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following method which works fine, it skips disabled fields and focus moves to the next active text input. My form has text fields, checkboxes and select lists. How do I add the type select to this so it navigates to type text or select?

I've tried `[type=text:select]` but it doesn't work

```
 $('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=text]:enabled:not(:read-only)')[$('input[type=text]:enabled:not(:read-only)').index(this)+1].focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple selector syntax, also cache the result of the element selection to avoid duplication

```
$('input, select').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $els = $('input:text, select').filter(':enabled:not([readonly])');
        $els.eq($els.index(this) + 1).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: That gives a syntax error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: read-only`

Comment: This works and it will advance to the first select input, but it will not focus to the next input when focus is currently on the select input

Comment: The solution to the above comment was to add select to the on action as follows: `$("input, select").on("keydown", function (e){})`